# Why was this question put on hold?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

Not my question, but why is this on hold?

[Accidentally applied to my current company](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/101355/accidentally-applied-to-my-current-company)

Those related questions linked in the comments don't answer this question. It doesn't seem more opinion based than any other question I see on here. This seems like a well asked on topic question to me.

Comment: FWIW, I had voted to close as unclear what you're asking because you have 4 separate questions there and it is not clear what exactly you were looking for help with. Besides, at least the first 2 of those questions are impossible to answer. We can't know if your company blacklisted you or you hurt your prospects. The 4th question is also rather too broad to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the actual questions stated:

> • Have I been blacklisted in any way by my current company?
>   • Did I hurt my standing or prospects within the organisation by
>    revealing I was job hunting (actually testing the waters)?
>   • Which are the likely consequences of my actions and how should I
>    navigate this situation?
>   • How should I act in the future? (Assume I'm a standard worker with
>    standard motivations).

Are fairly arbitrary nature and open to interpretation/opinion/guesswork.

People often close questions based on the exact question without taking a step back to see a potential larger picture.  Don't forget that a closure is notionally a "invitation to improve your question", although in many cases, it's simply take as a closure/rejection.

I happened to answer this, but I sidestepped these questions and just addressed the bottom line.  This is just the way I am sometimes, and I do tend to ignore the empirical demands of stack question assessments in order to serve the questioner more than the stack.

Comment: Yeah. It's somewhat asking for mind reading too because the only way to really answer the questions the OP is asking is to be the company they applied to and currently work for and see what their answers are..